# Read a file with unknown number of lines in C using fscanf

Tags: c, file, for-loop

I tried to search for the answer here and elsewhere on the Internet, but didn't get exactly what I am looking for. I have a data file that looks like this:

```
0,4
0,6
0,9
0,10
1,5
1,7
1,9
2,6
2,8
2,10
3,4
3,7
```

I can read this file line by line using `fscanf` without any issue. However, I don't know the number of lines in the file. I tried using the for loop with a very large number of iterations:

```
int u, v;
FILE *ptr = fopen("myfile.dat", "w");
for (int i=0; i < 1000000; ++i){
    fscanf(ptr, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v);
}
fclose(ptr);
```

However, this keeps repeatedly reading the last line of the file after previous lines are read. Why does this happen? And how do I correctly address my problem so that I would be able to read a file with unknown number of lines correctly?

**Edit:** Here is the minimal working example that I tried after seeing some answers below.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
FILE *file_ptr_edges;
file_ptr_edges = fopen("myfile.dat", "r");
int u, v, eof;
int r = 1;
while (r != EOF){
r = fscanf(file_ptr_edges, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v);
printf("u = %d,v = %d\n", u, v);
printf("%d\n", r);
}
fclose(file_ptr_edges);

```
return 0;
```

}

**Output:**

```
u = 0,v = 4
2
u = 0,v = 6
2
u = 0,v = 9
2
u = 0,v = 10
2
u = 1,v = 5
2
u = 1,v = 7
2
u = 1,v = 9
2
u = 2,v = 6
2
u = 2,v = 8
2
u = 2,v = 10
2
u = 3,v = 4
2
u = 3,v = 7
2
u = 3,v = 7
-1
```

Thus `r` seems to take value `-1` when the last line is reached. This solves my problem although I don't understand how the values of `r` are changing.

Comment: for starters, invoke `fopen` instead of `open`. Pass `&u` and `&v` into fscanf instead of `u` and `v`.  Allan's answer below takes care of the rest.

Comment: @selbie: Sorry those were typos.

Comment: Post data as text instead of image, and provide [mre] so we can run your code otherwise our only tool is inspection.  No need to apologize but it's a good idea to update your questions as you get feedback.

Comment: @AllanWind : Please see the edited question.

Comment: @Peaceful good job, but now it's a different question.  You have two calls to fscanf and throw every 2nd result away.

Comment: @AllanWind: I see what you mean. Thank you. I tried assigning the result  of `fscanf` to an integer but I am not able to make it work. What values are returned by `fscanf` for EOF and otherwise?

Comment: See my updated answer if you haven't.  Per `man fscanf`: "On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this  can  be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure."

Comment: @AllanWind: Thanks for your help. I could make my code work. But please see my edit to the question. I would like to understand the behavior of `r`.

Comment: You need to check the return value of `fscanf` before you can use the value of `u` and `v`.  On my system stdio.h defines EOF as -1.  Open a new question if you need more help with a different question.

Comment: @AllanWind: Yes. Instead of `break` statement, `do while` is more elegant solution for that.

Comment: Appended code `while (r != EOF){  r = fscanf(file_ptr_edges, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v); ...  }` is an infinite loop should `fscanf()` return 0 or 1.  Best to not use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate your loop when `fscanf()` returns `EOF` (end of file):

```
int r = fscanf(ptr, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v);
if(r == EOF) break;
```

Note, `u` is only valid for `r > 0` and `v` for `r == 2`.  I don't know what behavior you want for `r == 0` or `r == 1`.

Comment: Shouldn't u and v be passed by pointer?  `fscanf(ptr, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v)` ?

Comment: Yes.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the result of `fscanf` (and every other standard library function you call that returns a result).

> The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Something like this should work:

```
while (fscanf(ptr, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v) == 2) {
   // do something with the numbers
}
if (feof(ptr)) {
   // the file was read to the end
} else {
   // there was an error
   perror ("Could not read the input");
}
```

Also, please read [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: Good use of checking `fscanf()` result against 2, the desired result instead of `EOF`, which is just one of the potential undesired results.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I wonder why you said that. What's wrong with using EOF?

Comment: @Peaceful If you type something like `42 foobar`, which is an error, the result will be 1 and not EOF.

Comment: @Peaceful If `fscanf(ptr, "%d,%d\n", u, v)` returned 1, what do you want code to do?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica fixed stdin->ptr

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Then why does the answer above compares that with 2 instead of 1? Also, why not to compare it directly with EOF?

Comment: 2 means continue, EOF means stop quietly, anything else means stop and complain. You can compare with EOF, but what do you do next if it's not EOF?

Comment: @Peaceful `fscanf(ptr, "%d,%d\n", &u, &v)` returns 2,1,0 or EOF.  You are only considering 2 and EOF.  [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72074223/read-a-file-with-unknown-number-of-lines-in-c-using-fscanf/72074275?noredirect=1#comment127353663_72074275), what do you want code to do if the `fscanf()` returns 1 or 0 (e.g. the scan was incomplete)?  Your answer to that question drives the answer of "What's wrong with using EOF?".